# How to allow internal requests within same container on different ports in ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-cdk, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a front-end and backed both deployed in same container and ports exposed

```
container.addPortMappings(
      {
        containerPort: 5000,
        hostPort: 5000,
        protocol: ecs.Protocol.TCP
      },
      {
        containerPort: 4200,
        hostPort: 4200,
        protocol: ecs.Protocol.TCP
      }
    )
```

also loadbalancer are defined and ports are exposed

```
const listener = ecsALB.addListener('HttpListener', {
      certificates: [sslCertificate],
      protocol: elbv2.ApplicationProtocol.HTTPS,
      sslPolicy: elbv2.SslPolicy.FORWARD_SECRECY_TLS12_RES,
      port: 443,
    });
listener.addTargets('ECS_ALB_ServerTarget', {
      port: 4200,
      healthCheck: {
        path: "/endpoint/health-check",
        port: "5000",
        interval: cdk.Duration.seconds(60),
        timeout: cdk.Duration.seconds(30),
        enabled: true,
        protocol: ecs.Protocol.HTTP
      },
      protocol: elbv2.ApplicationProtocol.HTTP,
      targets: [service.loadBalancerTarget({
        containerName: 'express-app-container',
        containerPort: 4200
      })],
    });

  }
```

in the front-end code I use   `post(`http://localhost:5000/endpoint/channel`)` to request data from backend, the front-end application is working and I also pretty sure backend is working as per ECS logs + health check point is working

```
ecsALB.connections.allowFromAnyIpv4(ec2.Port.tcp(80), "Ingress HTTP internet")
ecsALB.connections.allowFromAnyIpv4(ec2.Port.tcp(443), "Ingress HTTPS internet")


for (const subnet of vpc.publicSubnets) {
  asg.connections.allowFrom(ec2.Peer.ipv4(subnet.ipv4CidrBlock), ec2.Port.tcp(5000), "Ingress from ALB to App")
  asg.connections.allowFrom(ec2.Peer.ipv4(subnet.ipv4CidrBlock), ec2.Port.tcp(4200), "Ingress from ALB to App")

}
```

my problem is , on front-end I have a button which performs action by calling backend endpoint, am getting `ERR :: connection refused`, am not sure why, as per my understanding both services (FE and BE) are running within the same container and I didn't expect to face such issue

note : locally everything works fine

also I've seen an approach to add another target on different port ex; 445 mapped to port 5000 and use that instead, I didn't want to expose the `BE port` and use `LB domain.com` instead of `localhost`

Comment: Please define what your "front-end" code is. Is it a JavaScript app running in the web browser? Or is it something like a Python or NodeJS app running on the backend server? If it is a front-end SPA JavaScript app, then the `localhost` reference is going to try to connect to a service running on the user's local desktop/laptop instead of connecting to the ECS service.

Comment: it's indeed a reactJS app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your front-end ReactJS app runs in each user's web browser. It does not run on the server. All the server is doing is serving up the source files to the web browser. The web browser is where the code actually runs.

Because of that, when you try to reference `localhost` inside your ReactJS code, the code will try to connect to a service running on the local desktop/laptop that the web browser is running on. This probably works fine when you are testing your app locally, because you are running everything on the same computer that you are testing with.

For this to work in AWS/ECS, you will have to expose the backend to the Internet, via another listener on the load balancer (or something like a path based load balancer rule pointing to a different target port). After the backend is exposed to the Internet, you will need to change the reference to `localhost` in the React JavaScript code to reference the DNS name of the load balancer. Ideally you would have a custom domain name that you own pointed to the load balancer, and that would be the DNS name to use.

Comment: is there/what would be the best way to make the backend only accessible from the frontend ? (on another track am checking SSR)

Comment: You would need to add some level of security (JWT is a popular option here) between your front-end and back-end.